# Less override class and sub

Tags: css, less

I have Less statements for `rect:active` and `rect.myClass`. I'd like to have `rect.myClass:active` be the same as `rect.myClass`. How can I do this easily?

eg:

```
rect:active { opacity : 1 }
rect.myClass { opacity : .5 }
```

Now `rect.myClass:active` should also have `opacity : .5` except that its more stuff than just a one liner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't apply `:active` styles to the elemnt if it doen't have class `myClass`.

Less code

```
rect {
  &:not(.myClass) {
    &:active {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

  &.myClass {
    opacity: .5;
  }
}
```

compiles to css

```
rect:not(.myClass):active {
  opacity: 1;
}
rect.myClass {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```